# How can I remove, not the titlebar itself, but the title showing the application name?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, android-manifest

I´ve tried setting the

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

to

```
android:label=""
```

in the Manifest file.

This works in some way, the problem is that this also removes the title under the app icon on the phones desktop.

Comment: You better set the ActionBar text to "".

Answer (score 1):

`setTitle("");` will do that in onCreate() i suppose.

Comment: Easy as that! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Unfortunately this still blinks the original title for a quarter of a second.

Comment: I agree that some animation would be nice here. ;-).

Answer (score 1):

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in Action Bar:

You have to override

```
android:actionBarStyle
```

and then in your custom style you have to override

```
android:titleTextStyle
```

Here's a sample.

In my themes.xml:

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

And in my styles.xml:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="NoTitleText">
    <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
```